# How can I choose to show only failed result and result must be fail not pass

Tags: robotframework

there are 22  records on both tables. at records 1-21 it's was right but on record 22 on both table can't compare cause it's not equal. I would like to show result only failed record that's can't compare and let result fail.

```
connect to database using custom params  cx_Oracle    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}
@{queryResults1}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_A Order by SECURITY_ID
Log  ${queryResults1}

@{queryResults2}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_B Order by SECURITY_ID
Log  ${queryResults2}

should be equal   ${queryResults1}  ${queryResults2}



Disconnect From Database
```